# How to animate Sliding Drawer?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

[image: My activity]

When i push button start i need to get this:

:[image]

So, i have sliding drawer which i need to animate by clicking start button. As you can see context of sliding drawer contains seek bar and 3 buttons. When user click start button animation should start that should hide buttons.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_x="3dp"
    android:layout_y="374dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bcg9" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="106.6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rev" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="106.6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pause" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="106.6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/forv" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="11dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:maxHeight="3dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/animate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I try to use translate animation but when i click start button sliding drawer goes down, actually it disappear.

```
int topOfsd = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-sd.getHeight();
                Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,            0,topOfsd,topOfsd-100);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                sd.startAnimation(animation);
                sd.setVisibility(0);
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a handle on your SlidingDrawer using findViewById
You can just call the animateOpen and animateClose functions.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html#animateOpen()

If you don't want the sliding drawer to open all the way, just set the height to something in dips.

Comment: Hi, but the problem is I do not want to close it completely, see second picture, seek bar has to be visible.

Comment: If someone have an idea how could this can be done let me know, please.

Comment: Humm. I wonder if your can just add padding. Why are the controls in the sliding drawer? Seems very disruptive to be moving them. Perhaps you should think about redesigning. You can have the controls always at the bottom and then put your sliding drawer about that.

Comment: I decided for sliding drawer because of client requirement, he asked: with sliding up music control pring up, and with sliding down music controls hides, but in the meantime he added another requirement.If song is played and there is no touch event, then should start animation which is shown on the pictures above(music controls goes down so that the only visibile part of music control is seek bar).  Do you have idea how can this be done without sliding drawer(i have ideto wrap up music controls in some viewGroup and do translate animation)?

Comment: updated answer. Just set the height to something in dips. That should work. Mark if it does and let me know if it doesn't and I'll dig more through my app.

Comment: I think u didn't understand me fully, look at pictures, when sliding drawer is in open position and when there is no touch events for 10 seconds than animation should start in which sliding drawer needs to go down so the only visible thing of the content is seek bar.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with property animation.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int y = display.getHeight();
android.widget.SlidingDrawer  sd;
sd = (android.widget.SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
sd.animate().translationY(someValue);
```